# Entity Framework 6 - Database First - String Length Attribute missing

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I am using EF6 database first to create my EF 6 DB Context. The POCOs that are created are missing the property attributes such as "StringLength" or "Required". I have been on projects before where these were created for me and thought it was base functionality. Where can I find documentation on how to configure this behavior?

From a new Winform application I added a new ADO.Net Entity Data Model to my project and followed the wizard for "EF Design from database".

**Environment**

- New .Net Framework 4.72 Winform app
- EF 6
- C#

Comment: That means you created an old-style EDMX. Use "code-first from database".

Comment: Are you saying it used EF 5 when creating the POCOs? I don't think that would be possible since the project only references EF6.

Comment: No, I didn't say that. EDMX is also possible in EF6, it's just old style.

Comment: How would I generate a new style EDMX?

Comment: You don't understand. EDMX is old style. Just try the other option I mentioned.

Comment: Could you provide reference to the documentation for what you are considering the old style and new style?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what happened. By default [Scaffold-DBContext's parameter DataAnnotations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/cli/powershell) defaults to use [Fluent API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/code-first/fluent/types-and-properties). Fluent API configures the properties using function chaining in the OnModelCreating method of the context.  The DataAnnotations parameter is a switch, so just specifying the parameter will change the engine to use Data Annotations.

This is important to be because I use the EF Models outside of EF as well. There is a big benefit using them with ASP.net because it will use the annotations during request to validate the models.